# Ionic 2: how can I use functions such as startStateNotifications() using ionic-native's BLE plugin?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I'm currently using the [cordova-plugin-ble-central](https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central) plugin in an Ionic 1 app. I'm converting this app to Ionic 2, so I want to use this plugin through [ionic-native](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/ble/).

The issue is that some of the plugin's functions are not available through ionic-native. For example, the function `ble.startStateNotifications(success, failure);` is not available with ionic-native, whereas `ble.isEnabled(success, failure);` is (both are available in cordova-plugin-ble-central).

Do I have to use the plugin without ionic-native to be able to use all of it's methods?

==================

**EDIT**

Finally I used the plugin directly (outside ionic-native) and converted the callback functions to Observables like this :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

declare var ble;

@Injectable()
export class BLEService {
    constructor() {}

    BLEstartStateNotifications() {
        return new Observable((observer) => {
            ble.startStateNotifications((state) => {
                observer.next(state);
            }, (err) => {
                observer.error(err);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

And then you can call the function as an Observable:

```
this.BLEstartStateNotifications().subscribe((state) => {
    console.log(state);
}, (error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: No I didn't... So I'm just using the plugin directly, outside ionic-native, and I converted the callback functions to observables manually...

Comment: How? can you provide your answer?

Comment: Yes I edited my question !

Comment: Sorry to ask you much questions but its showing me error : 'can not find name ble' . Any other things needs to be imported in app?

Comment: Maybe you have to install it first using `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ble-central`